# How do you write wrapper module?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a download sub module, I would like it looks like this:

```
 Download.pm
 Download/Wget.pm
 Download/LWP.pm
 Download/Curl.pm
 Download/Socket.pm
```

My Download.pm should provide an api `sub download($url)`. It will look for LWP module, then `wget` command, then `curl` command, if non of these exist, it will use `Socket`.

How can I write wrapper module?

Comment: Using your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example, how i did it:
How it works? It checks for some condition, and creates object depends on this condition. And subroutine also checks for reference type and calls the right method

file /tmp/Adapt/Base.pm (base module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Adapt::Base;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self;
    if ( time % 3 ) {
        require "/tmp/Adapt/First.pm";
        $self = \Adapt::First->new(@_);
    }
    elsif ( time % 2 ){
        require "/tmp/Adapt/Second.pm";
        $self = \Adapt::Second->new(@_);
    }
    else {
        require "/tmp/Adapt/Default.pm";
        $self = \Adapt::Default->new(@_); 
    }
    bless( $self, $class );
}

sub somesub {
    my $s = shift;
    my $self = $$s;
    if ( ref( $self ) eq 'Adapt::First' ) {
        $self->firstsub();
    }
    elsif ( ref( $self ) eq 'Adapt::Second' ) {
        $self->secondsub();
    }
    else {
        $self->defaultsub();
    }
}

1;
```

file /tmp/Adapt/First.pm (some module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Adapt::First;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless( $self, $class );
}

sub firstsub {
    print "I am 1st sub.\n";
}

1;
```

file /tmp/Adapt/Second.pm (another module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Adapt::Second;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless( $self, $class );
}

sub secondsub {
    print "I am 2nd sub.\n";
}

1;
```

and file /tmp/Adapt/Default.pm (default module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Adapt::Default;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless( $self, $class );
}

sub defaultsub {
    print "I am default sub.\n";
}

1;
```

and test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

require '/tmp/Adapt/Base.pm';

for (0..10) {
    my $test = Adapt::Base->new;
    $test->somesub;
    sleep 1;
}
```

output:

```
dev# perl /tmp/adapt.pl
I am default sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am 2nd sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am default sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am 1st sub.
I am 2nd sub.
I am 1st sub.
dev#
```